# WebGL2 : incomplete framebuffer

Tags: javascript, webgl, framebuffer, webgl2

I'm porting a C++/OpenGL application into WebGL and I'm trying to create and configure a framebuffer.

The framebuffer has 3 textures we can write into of types : vec2, vec2, uint. `(gl.RG32F, gl.RG32F, gl.R32UI)`

Here is how I initialize the framebuffer :

```
var gbuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gbuffer);

var z0_texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, z0_texture);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RG32F, output_canvas.width, output_canvas.height, 0, gl.RG, gl.FLOAT, null);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, z0_texture, 0);

var zn_texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, zn_texture);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RG32F, output_canvas.width, output_canvas.height, 0, gl.RG, gl.FLOAT, null);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, gl.TEXTURE_2D, zn_texture, 0);

var n_texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, n_texture);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.R32UI, output_canvas.width, output_canvas.height, 0, gl.RED_INTEGER, gl.UNSIGNED_INT, null);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, gl.TEXTURE_2D, n_texture, 0);

gl.drawBuffers([gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT2]);
```

The framebuffer is incomplete : `gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER)` returns `gl.FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT` and shows a warning : `Framebuffer not complete. (status: 0x8cd6) COLOR_ATTACHMENT1: Attachment has an effective format of RG32F, which is not renderable.`

Any idea on what's wrong with my code?

Comment: *"Attachment has an effective format of RG32F, which is not renderable"* - What you do not understand?  `gl.RG32F` is not a renderable format. Therefore you cannot use it for a framebuffer. You must use a color renderable format. See [OpenGL ES 3.0 Specification - Table 3.13](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/es_spec_3.0.pdf#page=143&zoom=100,168,666) ([WebGL 2.0](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/) conforms closely to OpenGL ES 3.0)

Comment: I don't want to render these textures. I am using them in post-processing. That's what I did in C++ but can't do the same in WebGL.

Comment: No. You cannot do the same in WebGL. In OpenGL `RG32F` is color renderable. However, WebGL is based on OpenGL ES. In OpenGL ES `gl.RG32F` is not a color renderable format. "color renderable" does not mean that you can render these textures. That means you can render into a texture using this format.

Comment: @Rabbid76 ok thanks. Good to know

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want to render these textures. I am using them in post-processing. That's what I did in C++ but can't do the same in WebGL.

No. You cannot do the same in WebGL.

The error meassage *"Attachment has an effective format of RG32F, which is not renderable"* - means that `gl.RG32F` is not a renderable format. Therefore you cannot use it for a framebuffer. You must use a color renderable format. See [OpenGL ES 3.0 Specification - Table 3.13](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/es_spec_3.0.pdf#page=143&zoom=100,168,666) ([WebGL 2.0](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/) conforms closely to OpenGL ES 3.0).
You can't do the same thing in WebGL as you can in *desktop* OpenGL. In *desktop* OpenGL `RG32F` is color renderable. However, WebGL is based on OpenGL ES. In OpenGL ES `RG32` is not a color renderable format. "color renderable" does not mean that you can render these textures. That means you can render into a texture using this format.